# PowerShell C# run command not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I have next code:

```
private void ExecutePowerShellCommand(string command)
        {
            try
            {             
                Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                rs.Open();
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = rs;
                    ps.AddCommand(command);
                    var psOutput = ps.Invoke();
                    LogPSHeader();
                    foreach (var item in psOutput)
                    {
                        if (item == null) continue;
                        LogPS(item.BaseObject.ToString());
                    }
                    if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0) LogPS("ERROR");
                    LogPSEnding();
                }
                //rs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Next is how i'm trying to call this method:

```
ExecutePowerShellCommand("Get-NetAdapter");
```

The problem that such code is not working and i don't know why. I want to have the same output as in console, but in my app. Every time i'm runnig code i'm getting different exceptions in debug attached mode, like:
 - Operation Cancelled Exception
 - Can't find 'Event.Format.ps1xml' file. When i'm putting this file to the folder of his search i'm getting request for the next file etc.
 - Next he couldn't find some file (i don't remember the exactly name of the file) in the folder 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Appx'.
If i'm trying to run c# program not from VS, but running compiled exe i'm getting next output:

> MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetAdapter", DeviceID =
>   "{4C67B2DB-572B-4CB8-9D0F-19AC7FE93B1B}", SystemCreationClassName =
>   "CIM_NetworkPort", SystemName = "w-KerbiczkovYuI.e-lab.icl.kazan.ru")
>
> MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetAdapter", DeviceID =
>   "{CBBC4607-17BB-4FFB-A93F-A08F17472C8A}", SystemCreationClassName =
>   "CIM_NetworkPort", SystemName = "w-KerbiczkovYuI.e-lab.icl.kazan.ru")
>
> MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetAdapter", DeviceID =
>   "{31950F9C-DF49-49A7-8BF9-CBD36F99D7CB}", SystemCreationClassName =
>   "CIM_NetworkPort", SystemName = "w-KerbiczkovYuI.e-lab.icl.kazan.ru")
>
> MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetAdapter", DeviceID =
>   "{B03679B3-199A-43D8-9088-E919658424B1}", SystemCreationClassName =
>   "CIM_NetworkPort", SystemName = "w-KerbiczkovYuI.e-lab.icl.kazan.ru")

I think every record in this output is for the interface (i have 4 interfaces).

If i'm working in PowerShell console - nothing bad and everything works as expected.
If i'm trying to execute, for example: `ExecutePowerShellCommand("Get-Process");` - no exceptions and i'm getting the result. Not the same as in the PS console, but without exception in VS.

What i'm doing wrong and how can i get expected result and have the same output as in the PowerShell console in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the stupid question. I have found an answer. I wanted to close the question but i can't and would answer here.
To have a good output as in the PS console i need to add command at the end of statement: `ps.AddCommand("Out-String")`. And remember, you need to redirect output to `Out-String` command. Don't use `AddStatement` between this two commands.
Second part of my question are strange exceptions. I still don't fully understand the nature of them, but as i understand they are internal powershell exceptions and catched by powershell class because i'm not catching any of this exception. Debugger just informing me about them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ps.AddScript(command)` instead of `ps.AddCommand(command)`

While invoking time it will give command result.